# Issue when trying to reload the fixtures

Tags: symfony

When I try to reload my fixtures using

> php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load

I'm getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`foo_db`.`Book`, CONSTRAINT `FK_C29271DD816C6140` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `Author` (`id`))

The error is showed when the status `"> purging database"` is showed.

This is my code:

```
class Book{
...

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Author", inversedBy="books")
 */
private $author;

... 
}

class Author{
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Book", mappedBy="author")
     */
    private $books;

}
```

More: my boss has the same code and it doesn't have that error.

Any idea?

sf 2.0.1 (just updated)/ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: have you rebuild the database?

Comment: yes, it's the only way to load the fixtures then.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I'm guessing correctly, you are using a MySQL database. If yes, then you are facing a bug/problem with the current version of the `doctrine-fixtures` library for Doctrine2. The problem is that they are using the `TRUNCATE` command to purge the current database values but this command has problem deleting foreign associations in MySQL.

See [this issue](https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures/issues/17) and [this one](https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures/pull/25) on the GitHub repository of the library for more information and workarounds.

In my particular case, I run this command from a script, so to make the command work correctly, I do:

```
php app/console doctrine:database:drop --force
php app/console doctrine:database:create

php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --append
```

This way, the purging is done by the `drop` command and appending has the same effect as not appending since the database is empty when the fixtures are loaded.

I must admit I don't know why your boss doesn't have the problem, maybe there is no book associated with an author in his database.

Hope this help.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: There is no book associated with his author. I had the same issue.

Comment: Be carefull if you have migration files!!! Then you should replace `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` with `php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`

Answer (score 4):

I've created a simple Event Subscriber class for Symfony 4. All you need to fix the self-referencing foreign keys issue is to add the below class somewhere to your Symfony 4 project.

This subscriber fires before each Symfony CLI command. In case if the command's name is `doctrine:fixtures:load`, it performs database purge, but doing `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0` first.

This solves the issue without any other modification.

```
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\ConsoleEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Event\ConsoleCommandEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class ConsoleCommandEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
    * @var EntityManagerInterface
    */
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            ConsoleEvents::COMMAND => 'onCommand',
        ];
    }

    public function onCommand(ConsoleCommandEvent $event)
    {
        if ($event->getCommand()->getName() === 'doctrine:fixtures:load') {
            $this->runCustomTruncate();
        }
    }

    private function runCustomTruncate()
    {
        $connection = $this->entityManager->getConnection();

        $connection->exec('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');

        $purger = new ORMPurger($this->entityManager);
        $purger->setPurgeMode(ORMPurger::PURGE_MODE_DELETE);
        $purger->purge();

        $connection->exec('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');
    }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't respect command line arguments, meaning it purges the database even if `-n|--no-interaction` isn't passed (i.e. when the user cancels, the database is still purged), it doesn't respect `--purge-exclusions`, and worst of all it even truncates when running the command with `--help` or invalid arguments. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64570346/doctrine-fixtures-how-to-override-the-purger-class/73358576#73358576) for a more error-proof solution.

Comment: @CodeCaster correct. That's why I called it "simple" :)

Comment: "This will truncate your entire database even if you don't want to" does not equal "simple", a warning is in place.

Comment: No. "Simple" means - it's just an idea, not a complete solution. Additionally, since fixtures are supposed to be used only in a testing / development environments, even if "truncate your entire database" is not what you intended to do, it shouldn't be very problematic.

Answer (score 3):

Add to your composer.json new section script

```
"scripts": {

    "load-fixtures": [
        "bin/console doctrine:database:drop --if-exists --force",
        "bin/console doctrine:database:create",
        "bin/console doctrine:mi:m",
        "bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load"
    ]
}
```

Then you can run `composer install && composer load-fixtures`

Comment: Very clever to reduce the amount of strokes you need to re-populate the entire database. Would it be possible and desirable to hook this into `doctrine:fixtures:load` so that this script is automatically executed? Or would that be a confusing solution?