# Doctrine fixtures how to override the purger class?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

From `doctrine-fixture-bundle` the `console doctrine:fixtures:load -n` command is defined here:

https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/blob/3.3.x/Command/LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand.php

I am wondering how can I extend the purger and use my own purger class?
`use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger;`

For example use this purger:
https://gist.github.com/Ocramius/96206e3b39e96bd64bc5

Comment: The example is a decorator of the default purger. I guess you may need to configure the new purger as a decorator: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html

Comment: @G1.3 good idea, haven't thought about it. I implemented another solution but it's very ugly.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a service definition for your purger and call the fixtures command with `--purger=my_purger` as described in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/current/index.html#specifying-purging-behavior).

As mentioned in the comments you can also decorate the default purger. To do that you can add the following to your `services.yaml`:

```
doctrine.fixtures_load_command.custom:
  decorates: doctrine.fixtures_load_command
  class: Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Command\LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand
  arguments:
    - '@doctrine.fixtures.loader'
    - '@doctrine'
    - { default: '@FixturesStuff\BrutalForeignKeyDisablingMySQLPurger' }
```

This overrides (decorates) the service definition for the fixtures command. And provides the command with a new default value.

This hooks into the specific implementation of the fixtures command, so it might change between versions. I am using Symfony 5.4, for your specific version it might look a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

The default purger is created by the default purger factory. On MySQL at least, purging complex relational graphs using the default purger is troublesome (see [Issue when trying to reload the fixtures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405356/issue-when-trying-to-reload-the-fixtures)), and the solution as you found is to disable foreign key checks during deletion.

There's three parts to the solution to do this by default, without having to explicitly specify a purger on each console command.

First create the purger, which simply inherits the `ORMPurger` as to not lose any functionality (particularly exclusions):

```php
<?php

namespace App\Doctrine\Fixtures;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class MySQLPurger extends ORMPurger
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function __construct(private readonly EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, array $excluded = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($this->entityManager, $excluded);
    }

    /**
     * Purges the MySQL database with temporarily disabled foreign key checks.
     *
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function purge(): void
    {
        $connection = $this->entityManager->getConnection();

        try {
            $connection->executeStatement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');

            parent::purge();
        } finally {
            $connection->executeStatement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');
        }
    }
}
```

Then create the factory that creates the purger:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Doctrine\Fixtures;

use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Purger\PurgerFactory;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\PurgerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class MySQLPurgerFactory implements PurgerFactory
{
    /**
     * Adapted from {@see \Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Purger\ORMPurgerFactory} to return a MySQL-specific {@see PurgerInterface}.
     *
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function createForEntityManager(
        ?string $emName,
        EntityManagerInterface $em,
        array $excluded = [],
        bool $purgeWithTruncate = false
    ): PurgerInterface {
        $purger = new MySQLPurger($em, $excluded);
        $purger->setPurgeMode($purgeWithTruncate ? ORMPurger::PURGE_MODE_TRUNCATE : ORMPurger::PURGE_MODE_DELETE);

        return $purger;
    }
}
```

Finally, override the default purger factory in your services configuration:

```yaml
services:
    # Override the default purger factory with the MySQLPurgerFactory, which skips foreign key checks.
    doctrine.fixtures.purger.orm_purger_factory:
        class: App\Doctrine\Fixtures\MySQLPurgerFactory
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.fixtures.purger_factory, alias: default }
```