# How should one implement a custom Doctrine purger when using Symfony 6?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, fixtures

The [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/current/index.html#specifying-purging-behavior) shows a solution, but it doesn't appear to work (i.e. Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Purger\PurgerFactory needs to be replaced with Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Purger\ORMPurgerFactory, and other changes).  I modified the code as shown below, but am pretty certain I am not doing it correctly.

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\DataFixtures\Purger;

use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Purger\PurgerFactory;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\PurgerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Purger\ORMPurgerFactory;

class CustomPurgerFactory implements PurgerFactory
{
    public function __construct(private ORMPurgerFactory $purgeFactory)
    {
    }

    public function createForEntityManager(?string $emName, EntityManagerInterface $em, array $excluded = [], bool $purgeWithTruncate = false) : PurgerInterface
    {                             
        // Change $excluded, $purgeWithTruncate as desired.
        return new CustomPurger($emName, $em, $excluded, $purgeWithTruncate, $this->purgeFactory);
    }
}
```

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\DataFixtures\Purger;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\PurgerInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurgerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Purger\ORMPurgerFactory;

class CustomPurger implements ORMPurgerInterface
{
    public function __construct(private ?string $emName, private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, private array $excluded, private bool $purgeWithTruncate, private ORMPurgerFactory $purgeFactory)
    {
        
    }
    public function setEntityManager(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager):void
    {
        // Seems rather redundent doing this even though I earlier inject $entityManager.
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function purge() : void
    {
        // Delete any tables which must be deleted first to prevent FK constraint errors.
        
        // This doesn't seem write.
        $purger = $this->purgeFactory->createForEntityManager($this->emName, $this->entityManager, $this->excluded, $this->purgeWithTruncate);
        
        $purger->purge();
    }
}
```

```yaml
services:
    App\DataFixtures\Purger\DoctrinePurgerFactory:
        tags:
            - { name: 'doctrine.fixtures.purger_factory', alias: 'my_purger' }
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine.fixtures.purger.orm_purger_factory'
```

Or should it be done by decorating the default purger as suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72619739/1032531)?

Answer (score 1):

Okay.  So you do have a few things wrong and the docs are somewhat out of date.  From a big picture point of view you want something like:

```
bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --purger=my_purger
```

to use your custom purger factory (aliased as my_purger) to instantiate and execute your custom purger's purge method.  The job of the factory is to just create the purger not to execute it.

I followed the docs and implemented PurgerInterface but the purge command complained about it not implementing ORMPurgerInterface which, as you noted, adds a seemingly superfluous method.  I think it is still a work in progress.  The default ORMPurger has a couple of additional public methods not defined in any interface which is also strange.  The fact that Doctrine is inconsistent with it's usage of the `Interface` suffix does not help.  But it is what it is.

This works under 6.1:

```
# CustomPurger.php
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurgerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class CustomPurger implements ORMPurgerInterface
{
    private EntityManagerInterface $em;

    public function setEntityManager(EntityManagerInterface $em) : void
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
    public function purge() : void
    {
        dd(' my purger');
    }
}

# CustomPurgerFactory.php
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Purger\PurgerFactory;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\PurgerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class CustomPurgerFactory implements PurgerFactory
{
    public function createForEntityManager(?string $emName, EntityManagerInterface $em, array $excluded = [], bool $purgeWithTruncate = false) : PurgerInterface
    {
        return new CustomPurger($em);
    }
}

# services.yaml
   App\Purger\CustomPurgerFactory:
        tags:
            - { name: 'doctrine.fixtures.purger_factory', alias: 'my_purger' }

bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --purger=my_purger
   > purging database
^ " my purger"
```

As far as decorating goes, you decorate a service when you want to modify some methods without extending the original class.  There is only one method here and it's quite a doozy so I don't think decorating will help.

If you wanted to always use your purger without the --purger option then you could probably point the default purger factory service id to your factory.  I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

One final note: I took a look at your decorating link.  Don't know what they were trying to do but I do know it has nothing to do with decorating.

Comment: Thanks Cerad,  My hopes were to perform my own purging as necessary and then use the default purger to do the rest, and `CustomPurger::purgeFactory` refers to the default purger factory and not my custom purger factory.  While my approach appears to work, just doesn't seem right.

Comment: That makes things a bit clearer.  If the purger itself was a service then it would be easy enough to decorate it such that your purge method could do it's thing then call the original purge.  But we are dealing with factories and I hate to say it, rather questionable interfaces.  So yes injecting the original ORMPurgerFactory service into your CustomPurgerFactory which in turn passes it to CustomPurger which in turn uses it to create ORMPurger is probably the best you can do.

Comment: Might actually be a bit cleaner to have CustomPurgerFactory create both CustomPurger and ORMPurger and then just pass the ORMPurger to the CustomPurger.  It would be almost like decorating.  I could update the answer if you want.