# Self referencing addReference getReference in the same fixture

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fixtures

I have a simple question about Fixtures in Symfony and Doctrine.
I have an Entity "Project" and I would like to self-referencing this project. For example I tried this :

```
$project1 = new Question();
$this->addReference("initiatives", $project1); //referencing
$project1->setItem('Project Initiatives');
$project1->setInverse(false);
$project1->setProjectHead($this->getReference("initiatives")); // get the reference of himself 
$manager->persist($project1);
```

My entity (extract) :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Project::class, inversedBy="projects")
 */
private $project_head;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Project::class, mappedBy="project_head")
 */
private $projects;

public function setProjectHead(?self $project_head): self
{
    $this->project_head = $project_head;

    return $this;
}
```

But It does not work. I have this error :
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

I have just ONE line in my db.
I think he can't UDPATE because when I try to add others fixtures, the message appears. But I don't know how to fix this.

Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood what your intention is here - why do you want to use the add and get reference in the same fixtures file like this? I.e. isn't that the same as just setting `$project1->setProjectHead($project1);` (and adding the reference after persist/flush if that is needed in some other fixtures file for something else)? Does that fail with the same error message?

Comment: Not enough informations. Try to enable query logging in your doctrine configuration and check what queries are failing.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't very clear... I find my solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405356/issue-when-trying-to-reload-the-fixtures Thanks.